# Python: numpy fftn over a list of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, fft

I am trying to efficiently `np.fft.fftn` and array of 2D numpy arrays. `V0` is an array of shape `(nvar,nx,ny)`, and I would like to perform FFT over each 2D array from the first dimension of `V0`. What I tried to do here is to compare between iteration over the first axis of `V0`, and compare it with a naive attempt to do a FFT over the whole multidimensional array:

```
In [45]: import numpy as np

In [46]: V0 = np.random.random((3,128,128))

In [47]: V0fft = []

In [48]: for i in xrange(V0.shape[0]):
    ...:     V0fft.append(np.fft.fftn(V0[i]))
    ...:     

In [49]: V0fftdirect = np.fft.fftn(V0)

In [50]: np.amax(np.abs(V0fft - V0fftdirect))
Out[50]: 16366.207818488827
```

So how can I do it correctly?

Comment: Try by specifying the axis `numpy.fft.fftn(a, s=None, axes=0, norm=None)`

Comment: Trying this `V0fftdirect = np.fft.fftn(V0, s=None, axes=0, norm=None)` leads to an error : `TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable`

Comment: Sorry, `axes` should be a sequence : `numpy.fft.fftn(a, s=None, axes=(0), norm=None)`

Comment: It works, but for some reason it still doesn't give me the same result as by iterating over the first axis index  - `In [75]: np.amax(np.abs(V0fft - V0fftdirect))
Out[75]: 8226.2612029266456`

Comment: In the for loop, replace `np.fft.fftn` by `np.fft.fft2`

Comment: Changing to fft2 for `V0fftdirect = np.fft.fft2(V0)` did the job..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Replace `np.fft.fftn` by `np.fft.fft2` in the for loop.
- Specify the `fftn` axis : `numpy.fft.fftn(a, s=None, axes=(-2, -1), norm=None)`

Comment: I think it should rather be `np.fft.fftn(V0,axes=(-2,-1))`

Answer (score 1):

`V0fftdirect = np.fft.fft2(V0)` did the job :

```
In [93]: import numpy as np

In [94]: V0 = np.random.random((3,128,128))

In [95]: V0fftfor = []

In [96]: for i in xrange(V0.shape[0]):
    ...:     V0fftfor.append(np.fft.fftn(V0[i]))
    ...:     

In [97]: V0fftdirect = np.fft.fft2(V0)

In [98]: np.amax(np.abs(V0fftfor - V0fftdirect))
Out[98]: 0.0
```